# Markov chain. Implementation add method

Tags: c, markov-chains, memmove

I am a bit confused with the next statment in implementation:

```
void add(char *prefix[NPREF], char *suffix) {
    State *sp;

    sp = lookup(prefix, 1);
    //addsuffix(sp, suffix);

    printf("size of prefix %d",&prefix);
    printf("size of prefix %s", prefix + 1);
    printf("size of prefix %d \n", &prefix+1);
    for (int i = 0; i < NPREF; i++)
        printf("%s \n" , prefix[i]);


    printf("memmove \n");

    memmove(prefix, prefix + 1, (NPREF - 1) * sizeof(prefix[0]));
    prefix[NPREF - 1] = suffix;

    for (int i = 0; i < NPREF; i++)
        printf("%s \n", prefix[i]);

}
```

**mmemove(prefix, prefix + 1, (NPREF - 1) * sizeof(prefix[0]));**

So prefix is a pointer of type char. In this terms prefix + 1 is the link to the next char in the array, isn't it?

How is it works in the right way? I've read about memmove and read about pointers but couldn't explore this add function behaviore for myself.

Comment: printf("size of prefix %d",&prefix); is wrong

Comment: I am just trying get answer. Please dont take care about my printf functions. Question is not about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So prefix is a pointer of type `char`. In this terms `prefix + 1` is
>   the link to the next `char` in the array, isn't it?

No and yes. `prefix` is not a pointer to `char`, it is an array of `NPREF` pointers to `char`. The size of this array is

```
assert(sizeof(prefix) == NPREF * sizeof(char*)
```

and yes `prefix + 1` is address of next element after `&prefix[0]` because `prefix` (which is array) decays to pointer to array's first element. 
So

```
memmove(prefix, prefix + 1, (NPREF - 1) * sizeof(prefix[0]));
```

will `mommove` `NPREF - 1` elements by one location. Sounds reasonable taking into account what Markov chain is, though we can't see your implementation. If it was instead written as

```
memmove(&prefix, &prefix + 1, sizeof(prefix)/sizeof(prefix[0]);
```

then it would `memmove` whole array.

Example:

```
[0][1][2][3][4][5]...[n] /* prefix was */
[A][B][C][D][E][F]...[N]
memmove(prefix, prefix + 1, (NPREF - 1) * sizeof(prefix[0]));
[0][1][2][3][4][5]...[n] /* prefix is */
[A][A][B][C][D][E]...[M]
```

Answer (score 0):

`memmove` will move n-1 pointers one step backwards.

Consider it for a second as `memcpy` that operates on 2 different arrays:

```
prefix
 V    
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
 ^  ^  ^  ^  ^
 \  \  \  \  \
  \  \  \  \  \
   \  \  \  \  \
    \  \  \  \  \
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
    ^
    prefix+1
```